Should I remove mosses and liverworts growing in Venus flytrap's pot?
My Venus flytrap (Dionaea muscipula) is growing in 100% peat moss in a 4 inch diameter pot. Over the last few months, a species of moss (not sphagnum) and a species of liverwort have also grown on the peat moss. Around 25% of the top surface of the peat moss is now covered in moss, and another 25% is covered by a liverwort. Should the moss and liverwort be considered weeds and be completely removed?

Yes, the moss and liverwort should be considered as weeds and thus removed. They also can compete with your Venus flytrap for resources such as water, light, and nutrients potentially affecting the growth and health of it. If you will remove them it will ensure your Venus flytrap will be in the best situation to thrive.
